# Location errada com Chrome e Firefox

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou capturando o location de um elemento imagem. Quando busco pelo Phantom, traz as coordenadas X/Y corretas, porém se faço pelo Chrome ou pelo Firefox, ele dá outro location e aí não consigo pegar o conteúdo do elemento.

Veja abaixo as coordenadas do mesmo elemento, capturada com o Phantom e com o Chrome:

Coordenadas pelo Phantom:
X = 0x00000375
Y = 0x00000180

Coordenadas pelo Chrome:
X = 0x000003c1
Y = 0x00000184

Comment: nesses casos cada navegador vai ter a sua particularidade de posicionamento. Não sei a tua finalidade mas teria de capturar esse location diferente para cada navegador que estiver usando.

Comment: Não deveria ser. O element.location deve ser o mesmo, independente do browser, não é?
Todas as pesquisas que faço para obter o printscreen do elemento, a função é sempre a mesma. Então concluo que deveria ser igual.
Minha desconfiança é que a minha máquina tenha algum problema com relação ao posicionamento, pois quando rodo pelo Phantom, ele não tem GUI

Comment: Resolvi (parcialmente) rodando o Chrome e o Firefox em HEADLESS mode. Sendo assim não tem GUI e aí funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Phantom é headless, por isso vai dar diferença.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o problema: no computador que estou usando, o ajuste de escala e layout do vídeo estava em 125%, conforme recomendado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta alteração fazia com que o driver capturasse as coordenadas desposicionadas e por isso funcionava em headless, já que não usava a GUI.

Voltei para 100% de exibição e funcionou perfeitamente.